# Copying a pandas column, giving the values based on previous columns

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe which looks as below:

```
column = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data = [[20, 5, 22], 
        [21, 6, 23], 
        [22, 7, 24], 
        [23, 8, 25], 
        [24, 9, 26],
        [25, 10, 27], 
        [26, 11, 28], 
        [27, 12, 29], 
        [28, 13, 30], 
        [29, 14, 31]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column)
```

The column `A` and `B` are linked, as if `A=23`, `B=8`. I wish to create a new column `D`, where if `C=23`, inthat row also `D=8`.

The aim is to get the second dataframe to look as below:

```
column = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = [[20, 5, 22, 7], 
        [21, 6, 23, 8], 
        [22, 7, 24, 9], 
        [23, 8, 25, 10], 
        [24, 9, 26, 11],
        [25, 10, 27, 12], 
        [26, 11, 28, 13], 
        [27, 12, 29, 14], 
        [28, 13, 30, NaN], 
        [29, 14, 31, NaN]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column)
```

In the actual dataframe there are 4000 rows. This is a minimal working example to visualise the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the logic to create column `D`. How do you compute the values for this column ?

Comment: Why the last 3 values are NaN?

Comment: The column D is based on the value of C in that row. If C=25, I want to look if there is a row where A=25. The value of B in the row where A=25, is the value of D where C=25.

Comment: A=25, B=3 -> C=25, D=3. Sorry I'm struggling to properly communicate the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your explanation and sample data, there must be only last 2 `NaN`

```
df['D'] = df.C.map(df.set_index('A')['B'])

Out[79]:
    A   B   C     D
0  20   5  22   7.0
1  21   6  23   8.0
2  22   7  24   9.0
3  23   8  25  10.0
4  24   9  26  11.0
5  25  10  27  12.0
6  26  11  28  13.0
7  27  12  29  14.0
8  28  13  30   NaN
9  29  14  31   NaN
```

as in row 7 `C=29`, there is `A=29 and C=14`, so `D` will be `14` instead of `NaN`